# Error while import the data from MySQL to HBase using Sqoop --query?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, data-import, sqoop

When I import selected data from MySQL to HBase using Sqoop as follow:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx/db_company 
--username root 
--password root 
--query 'SELECT id,name FROM basic_info WHERE $CONDITIONS LIMIT 100' 
--hbase-table sls-basic-info 
--hbase-row-key id 
--split-by id -m 1 
--column-family f
```

It returns ERROR message:

```
17/06/09 16:29:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/06/09 16:32:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id:
attempt_1496989037668_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:     
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

My MySQL server is provided by remote cloud service.

Comment: it's not a good practice to share actual address and it's not needed to answer your question.

Comment: @Deng I said in positive way man.

Comment: _"remote cloud service"_ -- does that mean the JDBC connection has to pass through an internet proxy?

Answer (score 0):

That error message actually means *"could not reach the MySQL service - maybe the address/port is wrong, maybe it's not possible to reach this address/port because of networking restrictions, maybe the server is down - enjoy the next phase of debugging"*.

---

**If** your cluster nodes are in a restricted sub-network and have **no access to internet** *(which makes sense, for security reasons)*, then Sqoop mappers cannot reach your *"remote cloud service"* -- game over.
You will have to try something else, like running a Spark "local" job on another server that has access to internet *[see below for the proxy configuration]*

---

**If** your cluster nodes have access to internet via an **internet proxy** *(which is a bit lax on security, but after all, maybe you have no sensitive data in there)*, then you have to configure your Sqoop mappers so that they know about the proxy. Spoiler: it's complicated. I don't even know if it's feasible.

First, you must check with your Network Admin team about the proxy itself -- do they maintain a HTTP proxy, an HTTPS proxy, a SOCKS proxy? on which host (or which DNS alias masking a pool of nodes)? on which port? do they require user/password authentication, or not?

Then you must translate that information into Java system properties, as explained in the Java documentation page for [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).
Note that the documentation hides many embarrassing points:

- you cannot use an HTTP/HTTPS proxy for anything else than a HTTP/HTTPS request; that won't work for JDBC *(to be precise, it would require a recent version of Java and custom Java code - something you cannot do here with Sqoop)*
- you cannot use authentication with an HTTP/HTTPS proxy *(to be precise, it would require [custom Java code](https://blogs.oracle.com/wssfc/handling-proxy-server-authentication-requests-in-java) - something you cannot do here with Sqoop)*
- you can use authentication with a SOCKS proxy but it's documented elsewhere, in the dark corner of [Networking properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- if you configure Java to use a SOCKS proxy, then all traffic will attempt to go through that proxy -- including the background Hadoop communication; therefore AFAIK you cannot use it with a Sqoop mapper because it would simply disconnect the mapper from its YARN AppMaster!

Last but not least, you have to pass the appropriate Java properties to the Sqoop mappers.
The proper way to pass a Java property to the mappers is to override the (poorly documented) Hadoop property `mapreduce.map.java.opts` -- it's not in the Hadoop docs, so unless you stumble on it on a blog post (such as [this one](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201462036-MapReduce-YARN-Memory-Parameters)) while looking for something else, you cannot know that it exists.

The tricky part is that your default Hadoop config (and/or Sqoop) might already use `mapreduce.map.java.opts` for their own purposes, and overriding their settings may cause the job to crash (e.g. no explicit `-Xmx` quota, process goes beyond what YARN allocated for the container, YARN kills the container mid-flight, all logs are lost).
So the safe way to reset that variable is to inspect its "default" value and report that in your custom value.

The [Sqoop documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments) states that, to pass a Hadoop property to the mappers, you can use either a config file or a command-line override `-D <hadoop_prop>=<value`>> note the space after `-D`...

In the end your Sqoop command-line could look like

```
... -D "mapreduce.map.java.opts=-DsocksProxyHost=xyz.abc -DsocksProxyPort=1080 -Xmx800M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" ...
```

**But at this point, you already know that you are doomed**: the only proxy type that Java could use out-of-the-box for a JDBC connection is SOCKS; and assuming that your company has indeed a SOCKS proxy available, then forcing the Sqoop mappers to use that proxy for all network traffic would cut off the necessary intra-cluster Hadoop communication.

---

***[Edit]*** There is a generic workaround for apps cannot be configured to use an internet proxy: download a **"proxyfier" utility** (there's a list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers)) on a specific node (inside or outside the cluster), and use it to open a kind of network tunnel to your remote MySQL database.

It's pretty inefficient, networking-wise, because all the data will have to be routed through the "proxyfier" node (in + out) plus a number of extra ethernet switches. And you will have to beg acceptance from your IT Security team before playing that dirty trick in Production.

*PS: speaking about efficiency... don't forget about `useCompression=true` parameter in your MySQL JDBC URL to reduce the network overhead.*